# app iOS accepted by Apple, crashes at launching, but works after plugging iPhone to the Mac/Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, crashlytics

UPDATE 2 :

We have at last a crash log : https://www.dropbox.com/s/62sq0ybyr4mhkkh/Screenshot%202015-09-02%2012.26.54.png?dl=0

It seems that a library is not loaded...

UPDATE 1:

Here's what we have :
- no crash log on Xcode with a device where the app crashes at launch
- We didn't run the app via Xcode, we downloaded it via Diawi
- We plugged the iPhone on the Mac, we didn't run the app via Xcode, we just looked at the crash log (nothing to see). After we unplugged the iPhone from the Mac, the app launches perfetecly ! Besides, when we uninstall the app and install it again via Diawi, it launches perfectly again !
- So the simple fact that we plugged the iPhone to the Mac makes the app work.

Any idea ?

### Below the first message

I have a serious issue with my iOS app, here's what we know :

- The app has been approved on App Store
- But if we download it via App Store promo codes (it's like a private beta), it crashes at launch, mostly on iOS 8.3 or below.
- We had the same issue by adding UDIDs and sending the app via Diawi before the submission
- We have already an app on the store (let's call it v1) and we have submitted a new version (v2) which has been a new project on Xcode.
- The crash happens with people who had already the app v1 as well as people who hadn't
- The crash remains even if you uninstall the v1 and install v2
- We put crashlytics : impossible to get any crash report, it crashes before the init, although we can see the launch page with the logo. We tried to put a delay of 10 seconds to let crashlytics initialize, but it doesn't last untill the 10 sec
- Weirdest thing : when we plug the device on Xcode to see what happens, then it works ! Impossible to see the crash again. Then, even if you uninstall and repeat the process by installing via Diawi, it will work ! As soon as you plug the iPhone on Xcode, it will always work...
- Some people told us that it crashes and it works the day after.

What we did :

- We updated the Pods
- We changed the certificates and provisionning profiles and made it clean
- We had some issues due to the Parse SDK, but we fixed it
- The target is iOS 7.1

Here are the pods that we have (screenshot):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzHfUya4Va4rb2dQSVJYazN1MFBxcG1DQnpBNXAybU9SVzk4/view?usp=sharing

Has someone seen already such an issue ? The weirdest thing is that Apple hasn't rejected it.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: We haven't published yet the app, but you can download it with this promo code on the app store : TWPA6FYN94KE

Comment: how can I download? i never download using promo code

Comment: You can go on the app store, then go to the bottom and click on "Codes".
Thanks !

Comment: What is in the device log during the launch attempt?

Comment: Unfortunateley, there is nothing in the device log. When you plug the device to XCode, the app launches perfectly, so it's impossible to know. We're gonna to try to have a crash log through Window>Devices>Device Logs. I'll let you know

Comment: have you figured this out?

Answer (score 0):

So I had exactly the same problem today with my app Macro Defense: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/macro-defense/id955086416?ls=1&mt=8

I found that by turning wi-fi off on the device, the app runs perfectly. If this is also the case with you, then my guess is that the problem lies in trying to perform some network functions in the appDelegate.

Have contacted apple support, and will repost if I get a definitive answer to this.

Cheers!

Comment: Hi ! I tried what you said, but it still crashes. I also tried with your app, and indeed it crashes when connected but launches perfectly in airplane mode.